# add `async` keyword into useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useEffect which is used to load content for dropdowns displayed into 2 components:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        };

        fetch('/portfolios', requestOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error(response.status);
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then(
                (portfolios) => {
                    props.onSetPortfolios(portfolios);
                    props.onSetFuturesPortfolios(portfolios);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }, []);
```

How I can add `async` keyword into this useEffect

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-glade-r9fy7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Vey strange. I see network call and response but the data into dropdown is empty. Any idea why?

Comment: See the response and then check how you are rendering the `dropdown`